# Error after starting the empty activity in android

Tags: java, android

Please refer the error message given below.Every time I am starting an empty activity, I am getting the following error. This is my 6th time trying every possible solution out there.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\cheik\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\396858f1c27f92ab2ca967b96e3a0da9\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\cheik\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\396858f1c27f92ab2ca967b96e3a0da9\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
C:\Users\cheik\OneDrive\Desktop\MYAPP\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(11) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(7) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(11) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\cheik\OneDrive\Desktop\MYAPP\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(514) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(514) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:13 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue a while ago with Android studio 3.5, have you tried to set:

`compileSdkVersion 28`  or `compileSdkVersion 29`  in my case, got to: app > build.gradle, this solved it for me.

- you can also try to file > invalidate caches / restart
- i noticed you're still on AppCompat 28 library, i suggest you migrate to AndroidX, Refactor > migrate to AndroidX